# Tweaking alignment of arrows in tikz-cd

Tags: math-mode, tikz-cd

Is there a way to tweak the alignment of arrows in tikz-cd? In particular, I'd like to align the `\bm{\hat{y}}` equation with the centre of the `\underbrace`.

I've tried using negative `\hspace`, and that works fine as long as there's only one arrow, but misaligns the second horizontal equals sign.

**Bonus 1:** I'd welcome suggestions on how to implement the `\underbrace` more elegantly than my current solution, which uses something like
`\left( matrixstuff \right. \left. morematrixstuff \right)`

**Bonus 2:** I'd also like to be able to equate the `0 \\ 1 \\ 2 \\ 3` column to `\bm{x}`, roughly where the `\bm{\hat{y}}` is now, and to the right of where I want the `\bm{\hat{y}}` to be. Combining multiple down arrows with the underbrace has so far defeated me.

**Code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd, amsmath, bm}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}[column sep = small]
        \begin{pmatrix}
            e_0 \\[0.5em] e_1 \\[0.5em] e_2 \\[0.5em] e_3
        \end{pmatrix} \arrow[r, equals] &
        \left(
            \begin{matrix}
                0 \\[0.5em] 1 \\[0.5em] 2 \\[0.5em] 3
            \end{matrix}
        \right. \hspace{0.9em} \arrow[d, equals] 
        & \hspace{-3em}
        \left.
            \underbrace{
                \begin{matrix}
                    -\frac{3}{5} + \frac{11}{10} \cdot 0 \\[0.5em]
                    -\frac{3}{5} + \frac{11}{10} \cdot 1 \\[0.5em]
                    -\frac{3}{5} + \frac{11}{10} \cdot 2 \\[0.5em]
                    -\frac{3}{5} + \frac{11}{10} \cdot 3
                \end{matrix}
            }
        \right)
        \arrow[d, equals] \arrow[r, equals]
        & \begin{pmatrix}
            -\frac{3}{5} \\[0.5em] \frac{3}{10} \\[0.5em] \frac{6}{5} \\[0.5em] -\frac{9}{10}
            \end{pmatrix} \\
        & \bm{y} & \bm{\hat{y}}
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for the question. Excuse me for this comment...but why do want use tikz-cd when you can you use simply the math-mode? I have not understood well your question. Can you put, please, an example to make with your hand (just only for the 2nd matrix). Thank you very much.

Comment: @Sebastiano Thanks for the +1. I use ```tikz-cd``` because I want to have equations going up-down as well as left-right. My previous solution for this was using the ```tabular``` environment. If I weren't trying to do something fancy, the second matrix would look like ```\begin{pmatrix}0-\frac{3}{5}+\frac{11}{10}\cdot0``` (etc.) ```\end{pmatrix}```

Comment: I have many problems with the English language :-) if I not see an output (done with the hand but very well), I not understand the problem.

Comment: @Sebastiano The second matrix in full, without underbrace or vertical equals signs, would be as follows. ```\begin{pmatrix}0-\frac{3}{5}+\frac{11}{10}\cdot0\\[0.5em]1-\frac{3}{5}+\frac{11}{10}\cdot1\\[0.5em]2-\frac{3}{5}+\frac{11}{10}\cdot2\\[0.5em]3-\frac{3}{5}+\frac{11}{10}\cdot3\end{pmatrix}```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some *ad hoc* processing.

The matrix body is processed twice to measure it with and without the lower part (in one case it is smashed). This allows to add a phantom with the correct height and depth.

Next the matrix is actually typeset with the lower part smashed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}

\begin{document}

Some text above the display, to show the context.
\[
\newcommand{\matrixbody}{%
  \begin{matrix}
  0-\frac{3}{5} + \frac{11}{10} \cdot 0 \\[0.5em]
  1-\frac{3}{5} + \frac{11}{10} \cdot 1 \\[0.5em]
  2-\frac{3}{5} + \frac{11}{10} \cdot 2 \\[0.5em]
  \AAAAA{3}\BBBBB{-\frac{3}{5} + \frac{11}{10} \cdot 3}
  \end{matrix}
}
\newcommand{\AAAAA}[1]{%
  \perhaps{\begin{array}[t]{@{}c@{}}
  \textstyle #1 \vphantom{\underbrace{\tfrac{1}{1}xxxxxx}} \\ \parallel \\ \bm{y}
  \end{array}}%
}
\newcommand{\BBBBB}[1]{%
  \perhaps{\begin{array}[t]{@{}c@{}}
  \,{\underbrace{\textstyle\!{}#1}\!}\, \\ \parallel \\ \hat{\bm{y}}
  \end{array}}%
}
\newcommand{\perhaps}[1]{\smash{#1}}
% fix the height
\sbox0{$\matrixbody$}%
\sbox2{\def\perhaps#1{#1}$\matrixbody$}%
\raisebox{2\dimexpr\ht0-\ht2}{\vphantom{\usebox{0}}}%
\begin{pmatrix} e_0 \\ e_1 \\ e_2 \\ e_3 \end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix} \matrixbody \end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
  -\frac{3}{5} \\[0.5em] \frac{3}{10} \\[0.5em] \frac{6}{5} \\[0.5em] -\frac{9}{10}
\end{pmatrix}
\]
Some text below the display, to show the context.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's the desired output. Where can I find information on the ```\perhaps``` command, please?

Comment: @mjc `\perhaps` is an *ad hoc* macro defined in the display. It will disappear as soon as the display ends, just like `\AAAAA` and `\BBBBB`.

Comment: Right, I missed it reading from the top. Thanks.

Comment: @mjc Hi, I have not understood your question ......When I have seen the code of egreg I have understood the reason of your question. I'm sorry to have not help you and I have deleted my answer. My best regards.